# Finding the right combination of skew, perspective, rotate, scale and transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

[image: sizes]

I am trying to get an image to fit a left and right screen via CSS. I am playing with chrome's developer console tweaking the different css transformation but I can't quite get it right.

I have the final rectangles so the angles and side lengths are known. I wonder - is there a way to calculate the CSS combination needed from the geometric sizes?